# Transit in Seoul, South Korea - Indonesian with a USA visa

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, indonesian-citizens, korean-air

I'm Indonesian, traveling to the USA through Seoul. I have a valid US visa and I will have a long transit at ICN airport. Can I leave the airport?

Comment: How long is the transit at ICN?

Comment: The first transit is 8 hours, the second is 13 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your US visa entitles you to a visa exemption for a maximum stay of 30 days, if you are traveling between Indonesia and the US. So you could indeed enter Korea and visit.

However the first transit, 8 hours, is a bit short – it would give you (especially someone who has I assume never been there, and might not navigate as quickly as an experienced traveler) about 4 hours of visit time. You would be better off doing one of those transit tours that the airport organizes (not sure if they still do it though). Or maybe take the monorail to the hotels nearby, and enjoy a meal, a stroll and a coffee before going back to the airport.

The second transit, 13 hours, is much better. You would have some time to visit the city – assuming it is daytime – and discover a little bit of Seoul. I would focus my visit around Seoul Station (the terminus of the AREX airport train) to make it safe. Namdaemun, Namsan Tower, Deoksu-gung, etc.